# passing varchar2 variable to oracle function from c#

Tags: c#, oracle, function

I'm testing oracle function calls from c#.
I've managed to write stable working test function and it's call.
here it is.

```
create or replace function abs.test_func(test_in in integer,test_varchar in varchar2)
return integer
is
test_out integer ;
BEGIN
test_out:=test_in;
RETURN test_out;
END;
```

c# call

```
using (var cmd = new OracleCommand("abs.test_func", conn1))
 {
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("test_in", OracleDbType.Int64, test_in, ParameterDirection.Input));
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("test_varchar", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000, test_varchar, ParameterDirection.Input));
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("test_out", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue));
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 JsonResponse.Result = Int32.Parse(cmd.Parameters[0].Value.ToString());
```

This code works perfectly.

Now I'm just doing the same, just put varchar2 input in front , before integer input.

```
create or replace function abs.test_func(test_varchar in varchar2, test_in in integer)
return integer
is
test_out integer ;
BEGIN
test_out:=test_in;
RETURN test_out;
END;
```

c# call

```
using (var cmd = new OracleCommand("abs.test_func", conn1))
 {
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("test_varchar", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2000, test_varchar, ParameterDirection.Input));
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("test_in", OracleDbType.Int64, test_in, ParameterDirection.Input));
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("test_out", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue));
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 JsonResponse.Result = Int32.Parse(cmd.Parameters[0].Value.ToString());
```

And my c# throughs error

> Input string was not in a correct format.

How can switching variables effect the outcome ????

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar bug, and it was resolved with

```
alter system set "_qkslvc_extended_bind_sz"=0 scope=spfile;
```

and restart database.
Probably it was fixed already in newer oracle versions.
What version do you use?